# Does CookieSyncManager need a valid instance of WebView?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a somewhat unusual situation in my app in which I cannot instantiate `WebView` in `onCreate()` but rather only later on in a callback (not even on the same thread).

As a result, the cookie cutter instructions (no pun intended) in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html), in which you call `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync()` in `Activity.onResume()` don't really apply in my situation.

This is because `CookieSyncManager::createInstance()` needs to be called **before** `CookieSyncManager::getInstance()`, but my callback is called **after** `Activity.onResume()` (where `CookieSyncManager::getInstance()` is called).

So my only recourse seems to move `CookieSyncManager::createInstance()` to `Activity.onResume()`, just before calling `CookieSyncManager::getInstance()`.

Which isn't really a good solution because, **unless I can check for the existence of a `CookieSyncManager` instance**, it's not a good idea to create more than one instance of `CookieSyncManager`... (it won't work properly anyway).

So I am thinking of perhaps move `CookieSyncManager::createInstance()`to `onCreate()` to be perfectly in line with the official documentation. The only problem is, an instance of `WebView` doesn't exist yet in `onCreate()`...

Hence my question: Does CookieSyncManager require a valid instance of WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can call CookieSyncManager before creating a WebView object, but then your WebView object's cookies will not be saved either.

Comment: Oh wow! I just finish testing call CookieSyncManager before creating a WebView object and it works, saving session cookies even after the application is killed. Nice. Your answer gave me the courage to try this out, so I am going to accept your answer although you said the cookies will *not* be saved.