# NullPointerException in CookieSyncManager.createInstance in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-cookiemanager

I have a class that extends from *AysncTask*. Inside the `doInBackground` method I want to update the cookies, so I have:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);      // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString); 
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

But I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the first line.

So, the **question** is:

- Why could be causing this ?
- Do I need to create it in another activity, and just used it in this activity ? how ? why ?

---

**Notes**:

- I know that my context is not null, I checked that.
- I can't have an *onCreate* method on an *AsyncTask*. [To do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156514/)

---

Here is the **stack-trace**:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
    at android.webkit.JniUtil.setContext(JniUtil.java:53)
    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:89)
    at com.t.m.library.HttpRequest.doInBackground(HttpRequest.java:129)
    at com.t.m.library.HttpRequest.doInBackground(HttpRequest.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

This is my **doInBackground** method:

```
request = new HttpGet(this.url);
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization", this.basicAuthentication);
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient httpclient = null;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);


// The content from the requested URL along with headers, etc.
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString); 
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

Comment: Please add relevant code and the stacktrace.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `CookieSyncManager`? It seems like the null pointer is that object.

Comment: well, that is one of my questions... I edited, please take a look. @algui91

Comment: I think that is the problem, Could you post the code for the `CookieSyncManager`. I would bet it isn't instantiated. To clear up any doubts, you could set a breakpoint in the line and see if, in fact, `CookieSyncManager` is `Null`.

Comment: how can I instantiated it ? what I posted is all the code I have for CookieSyncManager !, should it be more code ? @algui91

Answer (score 1):

I call it in `Application`'s `onCreate()` passing the application as context

Comment: No, it wasn't. But thank you... It's related to how to call the different function from different activities.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `CookieSyncManager`, but from what I can see in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) may be you should not use it within a Thread because its already creating one:

> A separate thread saves the cookies between, driven by a timer.

- You should call `createInstance` when the application starts, usually in `onCreate()`
- `getInstance().startSync()` In `Activity.onResume()`
- And `getInstance().stopSync()` in `Activity.onPause()`

[Here](http://call-me-early.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/android-cookiesyncmanager-to-prevent.html) you have an example

Hope this help.